# react native firebase check if user already exisits in real time database

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i need to check if username already exists in real time database then prompt user to select another username. it keep saying not found. I think it because of how my data is nested.

[image]

signup.js

```
const { email, username, password } = this.state;

    await firebase
                .auth()
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(async user => {
                    console.log('Data created', user);
                    let rootRef = firebase.database().ref()

                rootRef.child("users")
                        .orderByChild("username")
                        .equalTo(username)
                        .once("value")
                        .then(snapshot => {
                            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                                    let userData = snapshot.val()
                                console.log(userData)
                              Alert.alert('username is taken')
                                return userData;
                            }else {
                                console.log('not found')

                            }
                    })
```

Comment: show console log of userData

Comment: @JuniusL. the console log returns nothing, it goes to the else statement. PLease help

Comment: console log `rootRef`

Comment: @JuniusL.  i changed it to `let rootRef = firebase.database().ref('users')`. how can i access/ loop through all the uid /account / username while being performant. i i tried .child(`${uid}`) and .child(`"account`) but it comes back null.

Comment: so what does `rootRef` cotain?

Comment: @JuniusL. Reference `{path: "users", _refListeners: {…}, _database: Database, _query: Query}
path: "users"` and a snapshot contain` DataSnapshot {key: "users", ref: Reference, _value: {…}, _priority: null, _childKeys: Array(7)}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194078/discussion-between-junius-l-and-obumoon).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a user, then check if that user exists. Check if the user exists before creating the user.

```
const { email, username, password } = this.state;

let rootRef = firebase.database().ref();

rootRef
  .child('users')
  .orderByChild('username')
  .equalTo(username)
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      let userData = snapshot.val();
      console.log(userData);
      Alert.alert('username is taken');
      return userData;
    } else {
      console.log('not found');
      firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(async user => {
          console.log('Data created', user);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much it worked perfectly. I appreciate you taking the time to try to help me yesterday.