# Check if user with specified email already exists in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

On my signup page i want to check if a certain user with the an email that i specify exists or not. I did try the approach on the answer given to this question ([react native firebase check if user already exisits in real time database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334485/react-native-firebase-check-if-user-already-exisits-in-real-time-database)) but i get an error when i try to do that [image]

I am aware that when you are doing firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword it tells you weather user already exists or not, but for reasons that are complicated to explain, i dont want to do that for the time being. I do, however, have access to the config [image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the create user func is done on a different page from where the actual form its-self is, then the options are:

- Query the results as seen in the link above, given you fix the error
- Use [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) (the better option in my opinion), which gives you access to a number of useful functions, which won't require a form, one of which is:

  admin.auth.getUserByEmail(email)

There are several functions that will get you the information you need.

Here is a guide for adding the Admin SDK to your project (should you wish): https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Answer (score 0):

In the firebase console you can already set it up under Authentication -> Sign-in method tab and scroll down to the bottom you will see Advanced and set 'One account per email address'

[image]

Comment: I already have that turned on, basically, just to make things simple, before you are logged in, i want to see if a user weather the email that i specify already has an account or not

Comment: you'll just have to query the email then, what do you mean you don't want to do createUserWithEmailAndPassword ?

Comment: When you want to create a user in firebase, you do auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword, and if the user already exists, it gives an error that you can catch, what i meant was i dont want to do that

Comment: and how would i query the email? when i do "var rootRef = firebase.database().ref("users");" i get an error as you can see above. How do i query when i am not signed in yet?

Comment: how do you create the user data?

Comment: `

    const createUserWithEmailAndPassword = async () => {
        try {
            const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email,
            password,
            )

            generateUserDocument(user);

        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
            console.log(error);
        }
    };


`

Comment: hmm for some reason the backticks are not working properly and i cant write code, but anyhow, its what you see above this comment

Comment: you mean to say you are using this to sign up auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword, but you don't want to use the default firebase alert?

Comment: sort of, yes. Basically, in a nutshell, this func to create user is done on a DIFFERENT page from the page where the actual form input is, so i want to know if a user already exists on the form input page